# hostapd: WIFI AP cannot ping host connected to it

Tags: linux, networking, wifi, hostapd

I am working on an embedded Linux system (kernel-5.10.24), there is a RTL8723 WIFI module in my system.

Now I configured the target board as WIFI AP with hostapd/udhcpd/dnsmasq.

The hostapd.conf is.

```
interface=wlan0
driver=nl80211
ssid=TestWIFIAP
channel=1
hw_mode=g
macaddr_acl=0
auth_algs=1
ignore_broadcast_ssid=0
```

The udhcpd.conf is

```
start           192.168.0.20     #default: 192.168.0.20
end             192.168.0.254   #default: 192.168.0.254

# The interface that udhcpd will use
interface       wlan0           #default: eth0
remaining yes
......
opt       dns       8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4
opt       subnet    255.255.255.0
opt       router    192.168.0.1
```

The wlan0 in the system is configured with `192.168.0.1`

After starting hostapd/udhcpd, I can connect my Windows PC to the AP, the PC is allocated an IP of `192.168.0.20`.

I can ping the AP's IP `192.168.0.1` from PC, but I cannot ping my PC's IP `192.168.0.20` from within the AP.

The networking info in AP is.

```
# ifconfig
lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:40 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:40 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:3744 (3.6 KiB)  TX bytes:3744 (3.6 KiB)

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 30:95:87:XX:XX:XX
          inet addr:192.168.0.1  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:15966 errors:0 dropped:64 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:7603 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:20882819 (19.9 MiB)  TX bytes:647826 (632.6 KiB)

# route
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
192.168.0.0     *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 wlan0
```

Then I started to run `iperf -s` in the AP, and `iperf -c 192.168.0.1 -t 10` from my PC, it worked well.
But it failed if I ran `iperf -c 192.168.0.20 -t 10` in the AP.

I googled and found similar problems, but no solid solution/explanation of it.

The firewall settings in Linux AP is as follows,

```
# iptables -L
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

And the `arping -I wlan0 192.168.0.20` can get the MAC of the Windows PC. But ping from Linux AP to Windows PC still failed.

Comment: If they can communicate one way (but not the other) that means routes are ok and anything below routes so layer 2 is ok too. You should look for a firewall on the client instead. As the PC is Windows there's no solution for this on this Unix/Linux SE.

Comment: You can install on the Linux AP the command arping (usually from iputils-arping / iputils package/sources, rather than from arping package) and run `arping 192.168.0.20`: even if ICMP pings are blocked, usually ARP sortof pings are not.

Comment: In the Windows, I have WSL2 Linux installed. I can ping the AP from Windows command line and from WSL2 Linux. I will install arping in Linux AP, and try it.

Comment: I tried `arping -I wlan0 PC's IP`, it worked. I updated the question with `iptables` settings, there should be NO firewall for outgoing ICMP, but I don't know why `ping` from the AP is still failed.

Comment: The problem is on the Windows system.

Comment: I found out the root cause, and provided my own answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I did one more test, and got the answer.

I set the Linux board as host mode, and connected it to an WIFI AP in office, it got an IP of 192.168.95.77.
Then I connected the Windows PC to the same WIFI AP, its IP is 192.168.95.96.

I can ping from the Windows PC to the Linux board, but failed to ping from Linux board to the Windows PC, the same problem as I posted in the question.

So I checked with IT team, and be confirmed that the Windows PC is configured with firewall to reject input ping on the `192.168` subnetwork.